# What is the result of $4x^2-2y^2+4z^2 $?

Tags: factoring

> $$2x-y = y-2z = 4$$
>
> What is the result of $4x^2-2y^2+4z^2 $?

Factoring it and rewriting the term

$$2(2x^2-y^2+2z^2)$$

Once in a while, I've tried to factor it further. However, it is impossible to proceed anymore. Could you tell what I'm actually missing?

Regards!

Comment: $8(x-z){}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

$$2x - y = 4 \Rightarrow 2x = 4 + y$$
$$y - 2z = 4 \Rightarrow 2z = y - 4$$
$$4x^2 = 16 + 8y + y^2$$
$$4z^2 = 16 - 8y + y^2$$

can you take it from here?